# Threaded Websocket callback doesn't wake up after restoring connection

Tags: python, multithreading, websocket

I'm using `ThreadedWebsocketManager` and several streams like:

```py
from binance.streams import ThreadedWebsocketManager
twm = ThreadedWebsocketManager(apiKey, apiSecret)
twm.start_individual_symbol_ticker_futures_socket(callback=pair.startTicker, symbol=pair.symbol)
```

Callback `startTicker` works perfectly until it receives `{'e': 'error', 'm': 'Max reconnect retries reached'}`

This probably happens on my server when I'm loosing the connection (and I was able to reproduce it locally by switching off the Internet).

After the connection is on, the `startTicker` callback never wakes up again.

I tried the following (when the above exception was caught):

```py
- twm.stop() 
  twm.start() (failed due to "threads can only be started once")
- twm.stop_socket(socket_name) and restart
etc
```

Nothing helped me.

Is there a way to restore the `start_individual_symbol_ticker_futures_socket` stream callback?

Comment: hi, did you find solution for this? i'm just experiencing this too righ now